# How to print odd line in unix

Tags: awk, echo, cat

In a file, value `'20210813_20210816_20210818'` and `'20210813_20210816'` are coming in newline. In the below issue there are 2 DB records but coming in 4 lines instead of 2 . I want to print that two values which I mentioned using unix script.

This is not working:

```
cat filename.txt| awk 'NF' | while read n

do

10th_colum =`echo $n | awk 'NF'| awk '{print $10}'`

done
```

input:

```
20210908 ABC  ICICI            EFT  Rcvd     Staging Not_Rcvd Not_Rcvd Not_Dlvrd
20210813_20210816_20210818
20210908 CDE  HDFC            EFT  Rcvd     Staging Not_Rcvd Not_Rcvd Not_Dlvrd
20210813_20210816
```

Comment: Try: `awk 'NF == 1' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '!(NR%2)' file
20210813_20210816_20210818
20210813_20210816
```

Comment: Too bad there isn't a bitwise AND operator `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin ask and ye shall receive - https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Bitwise-Functions. Not sure how you'd use it in this case though.

Comment: `awk '(and(NR,1))'` ... `:)` .. PS -- thank you. I checked the very same manual, but with age I must be blind in one eye and I can't see out of the other...

Comment: Is there any difference performance-wise with `!(NR%2)` versus `(NR%2)==0`?

Comment: could you say how can I echo each 10 value in a single row of a table?

Comment: could you say how can I echo each 10 value in a single row of a table? cat filename|while read n do col1=`echo $n | awk 'NF'|awk '!(NR%2==0)' | awk '{print $1}'` .. till col9 it worked, but for col10=`echo $n | awk 'NF'| awk '!(NR%2==1)' |awk '{print $1}'` done-- not worked

Comment: @Daweo if there is I doubt it'd be noticable and I couldn't predict which would be faster. Write 2 scripts run them 3 times each on a 10 million line file to test it if you like.

Comment: @Monalizakhan [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are strongly discouraged, just ask a new followup question if you have one.