# How to echo each two lines in one line

Tags: bash, if-statement, unix, awk, echo

I have one txt file with below content:

```
20210910 ABC  ZZZ            EEE  Rcvd     Staging QV QV P
20210813_20210816_20210818
20210910 XYZ  YYY            EEE  Rcvd     Staging QV QV R
20210813_20210816
```

There are four rows. How to echo those in two rows. I am not getting how to write `if` statement in the below code. If the logic is correct please advice :

```
cat file.txt | while read n
do
    if [ row number odd ]
    then
        column1=`echo $n | awk 'NF' | awk '{print $1}'`
        column2=`echo $n | awk 'NF'| awk '{print $2}'`
        ...till column9
    else
        column10=`echo $n | awk 'NF'| awk '{print $1}'`

        [Printing all columns :
```

echo "  $column1 " >> ${tmpfn}

echo "  $column2 " >> ${tmpfn}

```
        ...till column10]

    fi
done
```

Output:

```
20210910 ABC  ZZZ            EEE  Rcvd     Staging QV QV P 20210813_20210816_20210818
20210910 XYZ  YYY            EEE  Rcvd     Staging QV QV R 20210813_20210816
```

Comment: Given that [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69136974/how-to-print-odd-line-in-unix) is nearly identical, it seems a bit odd that you did not attempt something similar to the accepted answer there.

Comment: As an aside, `awk 'NF' | awk '!(NR%2==0)' | awk '{print $1}'` can be refactored to just `awk 'NF && !(NR%2==0) {print $1}'`, and similarly for your other `awk | awk` pipelines.

Comment: Why not just `paste - - <file.txt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for an `if` statement. Just call `read` twice each time through the loop.

```
while read -r line1 && read -r line2
do
    printf "%s %s" "$line1" "$line2"
done < file.txt > "${tmpfn}"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a single `awk` script:

```
awk '{x=$0; getline y; print x, y}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Perl one-liner (it joins each pair of lines on the tab character):

```
perl -lne 'chomp( $s = <> ); print join "\t", $_, $s;' file.txt > out_file.txt
```

For example:

```
seq 1 4 | perl -lne 'chomp( $s = <> ); print join "\t", $_, $s;'
1       2
3       4
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.

Here,
`-n` and `-l` command line switches cause the script to read 1 line from STDIN or from file(s) on the command line (in a loop), and store it in variable `$_`, removing the terminal newline.
`chomp( $s = <> );` : Do the same as above, and store it in variable `$s`.
Now you have, for example, line 1 stored in `$_` and line 2 stored in `$s`.
`print join "\t", $_, $s;` : print the two lines delimited by tab.
Repeat the above.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)